# AEM query to fetch sling:resource nodes

Tags: sql, aem, query-builder, jcr

I want to know the list of component being used in xyz site. Querying to get all the sling:resourceType nodes but it failed to fetch the details

```
/jcr:root/content/xyz//element(nt:unstructured)/@sling:resourceType
```

Has anyone has any idea about this? Please also suggest if there is any other way around to know the component list.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the OOTB "Component Report":
http://localhost:4502/etc/reports/compreport.html

If you click "Edit" in the Editbar, you can configure the page path of your site in the "Root path" field. 
[image: Edit Component Report]

I think this report will show you all the info you need.

Comment: Looks like this is cool feature. Actually i want to edit the root path but I dont have the option edit.

Comment: @ezhil Maybe you don't have the right permissions? Are you logged as "admin"?

Comment: Looks like permission issue but I logged as admin, seeing only Report and Finish option, Edit option is not visible for me. Note - Using AEM 6.4 version.

Comment: Maybe that's an issue with 6.4 (I'm using 6.3 right now), but you can try to change the Root Path directly trough the CRXDE Lite. Go to `/etc/reports/compreport/jcr:content/report` and edit (or add) the property `rootPath` with your path.